# Redirect to a website after you win

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redirect, flash-cs5

I have a mini game (ad for a website). I have them winning after "x" score and the page in flash goes from the game (frame 1) to the win test page (frame 2). Instead of it advancing to the next frame, I want once the score reaches "x" to go straight to a website / signup page.

I have components in the game calling out to outside as3 pages.....

```
if(_root.score > 50){
_root.gotoAndStop(2);
trace("You Won!" ); }
```

I have tried to add this line of code in.....

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.website.com"), "_blank");
```

Comment: `I have tried to add this line of code in.....` and what happened?

Comment: 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method navigateToURL.    and also     1180: Call to a possibly undefined method URLRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the Class first:

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest; // You need this one too.
```

This is ActionScript 3. In ActionScript 2 you need to change `navigateToURL(new URLRequest(..))` to `getURL(..)`.
Seeing your code (`_root`) made me think you are using ActionScript 2.